# How to avoid mounting partition at startup in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 17.10

How to avoid mounting partition at startup in Ubuntu 17.10 in dual boot? I have 2 installations on the different device, one not mounts the partitions at startup/login, another mount all partitions found. Is there a configuration to switch on/off globally this behavior?

This is my fstab and blkid:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/fyCdTqCWdt/

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/fstab` is where all disk mounts occur at boot time.

Your second computer's `/etc/fstab` has additional disk mounts that the first computer doesn't perform.

To change the behaviour of the second computer, edit the `/etc/fstab` file, like so...

In `terminal`...

`sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bck` # to make a backup of the file

`sudo pico /etc/fstab` # edit the file

locate individual disk mounts, and place a `#` comment marker at the beginning of that line.

**Example:**

**change:**

`UUID=0C0F93CE58153D42 /media/username/Shared_Data ntfs-3g defaults 0 0`

**to:**

`#UUID=0C0F93CE58153D42 /media/username/Shared_Data ntfs-3g defaults 0 0`

**then:**

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> # to save the edits

<kbd>return</kbd> # to confirm the filename to save

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # to exit the editor

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

After reviewing your `blkid` and `fstab`, it looks like you've got an Android Development System (?) installed on your SSD that's created a bunch of ext4/ntfs partitions that get mounted. You've also got a second /boot/efi partition at /dev/sda4.

**Update #2:**

You have 4 partitions with the same UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b". Can't do that. Use `tune2fs` to change to unique UUID's.

Comment: I added my fstab and blkid configuration. The partitions aren't listed in the fstab, very strange.

Comment: @rkpisanu You've got an Android Development System (?) installed on your SSD that's created a bunch of ext4/ntfs partitions that get mounted. You've also got a second /boot/efi partition at /dev/sda4.

Comment: @rkpisanu if my answer(s) were helpful, please remember to vote/accept them. Thanks.

Comment: It is not an Android Development, it is Alfawise x5 mini pc. I resolve using GNOME Disks and set noauto flag to emmc partitions. But my question remains, because in other devices there isn't automount feature.

Comment: You have 4 partitions with the same UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b". Can't do that.

Comment: This UUID is made from official Intel Android flash firmware, not from Ubuntu. What is the issue to have the same UUID for 4 partitions?

Comment: @rkpisanu Take a look at your /etc/fstab. Note that the drives are referenced by UUID numbers. These UUID's should be specific to a particular partition, and only that one partition. If the system tries to mount UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b", which partition should mount? There's 4 that will respond. Use `tune2fs` to set individual UUID's.